# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de los elementos habiendo usado .value_counts() en una serie de pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Necesito encontrar la cantidad de veces que aparece el valor 'False' en este dataframe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código, donde dataframe es una variable que almacena un DF más grande. df_monday es este dataframe filtrado y counting_monday almacena una Serie obtenida del .value_counts().

```
    df_monday = dataframe.loc[:,'Per1':'Per10']
    counting_monday = df_monday.value_counts()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Que puedo hacer para guardar en una variable únicamente el valor numérico (15 en este caso)?

Comment: Hola Alejandro! Por favor crea un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  del DataFrame, así solo tendremos que copiar y pegar tu código de ejemplo y nos será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

para contar falsos en una fila:

```
(~df.loc['curso1']).sum()
```

Y en una columna:

```
(~df['per6']).sum()
```

Finalmente el dataframe completo:

```
(~df).sum().sum()
```

Espero te sirva.

También considerar la via NumPy (mejor performance) :

```
import numpy as np
```

```
# columna
sum(np.where(df['per6'],0,1)).sum()

# fila
sum(np.where(df.loc['curso1'],0,1)).sum()

# dataframe completo
sum(np.where(df,0,1)).sum()
```

El concepto subyaciente es que las variables booleanas son una subclase de int, y por tanto tienen valores numéricos, haciendo posible contar los positivos, sumándolos.

Ya que en este caso lo que buscamos es contar los ceros, el approach anterior requiere *negar* el objeto, es decir, convertir los falsos en  verdaderos y viceversa.

Esto se logra con el operador ~ en los tres primeros casos usando Pandas puro.

Usando NumPy, a la función np.where() se le pasa un 0 si la condición es positiva, y un 1 si es negativa, con lo que se consigue el mismo efecto.

[en esta pregunta se muestran varias alternativas y conceptos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415751/count-occurences-of-true-false-in-column-of-dataframe)